# How to set WPFExtensions.ZoomControl Default Zoom

Tags: wpf

Does anyone know how to set the default zoom level to 1:1 in the ZoomControl included in [wpfextensions](http://wpfextensions.codeplex.com/)?  When the project first starts the default behavior is to zoom to fill.

I have tried both

```
 <zoom:ZoomControl Mode="Original">
```

and

```
 <zoom:ZoomControl Zoom="1">
```

both didn't work...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you have to set the Mode property to `Original`, or you can explicitly call `ZoomToOriginal` in a Loaded event handler for the ZoomControl.

It also appears that the EqualityToBooleanConverter will throw an exception, when it shouldn't. The code looks like:

```
public class EqualityToBooleanConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return object.Equals(value, parameter);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if ((bool)value)
            return parameter;

        //it's false, so don't bind it back
        throw new Exception("EqualityToBooleanConverter: It's false, I won't bind back.");
    }
}
```

You would need to remove that exception and return [Binding.DoNothing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.donothing.aspx), instead.

That converter is used in the control template of ZoomControl, like so:

```
<RadioButton Content="1:1"
    GroupName="rbgZoomMode"
    IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},Path=Mode,Converter={StaticResource equalityConverter},ConverterParameter={x:Static Controls:ZoomControlModes.Original}}" />
<RadioButton Content="Fill"
    GroupName="rbgZoomMode"
    IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},Path=Mode,Converter={StaticResource equalityConverter},ConverterParameter={x:Static Controls:ZoomControlModes.Fill}}" />
```

So effectively, it's trying to only bind back to the source if value is true. But it throws an exception, as you've seen.

Comment: Tried that.  Maybe it isn't working because the contents of the ZoomControl are changing?

Comment: @Brian - Looks like it calls ZoomToFill in OnApplyTemplate, so you'd need to call ZoomToOriginal in a Loaded event handler.

Comment: I added an event handler for the ZoomControl's Loaded event and called ZoomToOriginal in the handler.  However it throws an Exception with the message "EqualityToBooleanConverter: It's false, I won't bind back."  Any idea what that is about?

Comment: Fixed the ConvertBack in EqualityToBooleanConverter in wpfextensions to return Binding.DoNothing and a ZoomToOriginal call when the Loaded event is triggered and everything works great.  Thanks!